# Реально ли сделать уникальное значение по отношению к другой колонке, в одной таблице?

Tags: mysql

Существует таблица:

```
CREATE TABLE `test` (
`id` INT( 11 ) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
`id_kvitanc` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
`id_magazin` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
) ENGINE = MYISAM
```

Так вот суть в следующем:
`id` - это соответственно уникальная запись,
`id_magazin` - это ИД магазина из другой таблицы, цифрами (1,2,3) 
`id_kvitanc` - это номер чека, который создал магазин.
Реально ли сделать так, чтобы, если `id_kvitanc=1` (например первый магазин), то невозможно было добавить запись с `id_kvitanc=500`, если `id_kvitanc=500` уже существует? (но для `id_magazin=2`, может быть `id_kvitanc=500`) точнее, чтобы `id_kvitanc` заполнялся уникально автоинкрементно?

Comment: А почему у вас id_kvitanc varchar как вы представляете автоинкрементальное заполнение текстового поля. И чем оно отличается от колонки id ?

Comment: Для уникальности нужно добавить constraint `UNIQUE(id_magazin, id_kvitanc)`. Автоинкремент на `id_kvitanc`, как на поле `id` cделать не получится, Вам придётся самому в коде это эмулировать..

Comment: id_kvitanc - это внешний ключ, во второй таблице квитанций он же будет первичным ключом, там и заполняйте автоикрементом.

Comment: Хорошо, если id_kvitanc сделать типом `int`, что-то от этого тогда получится? отличается тем что id - уникальная запись в таблице, а id_kvitanc могут быть одинакового значения, но с разными id_magazin, например: id=1, id_kvitanc=500, id_magazin=3 и id=2, id_kvitanc=500, id_magazin=4

Comment: прочтите Форта - sql, Линн Бейли - sql, там это очень хорошо раскрыто.

Comment: суть должна быть такая, что я запросом добавляю только поле `id_magazin` а остальное проставляется самостоятельно. `id` - не указываю, т.к. автоматически проставится, и соответственно необходимо чтобы если я делаю `INSERT id_magazin=1`, то автоматически занеслось следующая за `id_kvitanc=500`, т.е. 501

Comment: В mysql может быть только 1 автоинкрементное поле на таблицу.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для уникальности нужно добавить ограничение (constraint) `UNIQUE(id_magazin, id_kvitanc)`.

Unique на два поля даст именно то ограничение которое вы хотите.

```
  CREATE TABLE `test` (
      `id` INT( 11 ) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
      `id_kvitanc` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
      `id_magazin` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
      UNIQUE (id_magazin, id_kvitanc)
  ) ENGINE = MYISAM
-- это сработает без ошибок
insert into test (id_magazin, id_kvitanc) VALUES 
     (1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 1);

--сдесь будет ошибка, в магазине 1 уже есть квитанция 1.
insert into test (id_magazin, id_kvitanc) VALUES (1, 1);
```

Автоинкремент на `id_kvitanc`, как на поле `id` cделать не получится, Вам придётся самому в коде это эмулировать.

Можно к примеру создать таблицу в которой хранить максимальный номер 
квитанции.

```
create table last_kvitanc(
  id_magazin VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  max_id_kvitanc INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  UNIQUE (id_magazin)
);
```

В коде который добавляет квитанции:

1. Получать значение id_kvitance для заданного id_magazine.
2. Увеличить значение max_id_kvitance на 1 
           (сдесь нужно убедится что значение не изменялось с момента получения).
3. Сохранить квитанцию в таблицe test с полученным id_kvitance.

Comment: Arnial, вы очередной раз меня спасаете :) То, что нужно!